# beautify all python scripts in folder

Tags: python, apache

Requirement is to beautify all python scripts and show it.

I have done following configuration in `apache2.conf`

```
Alias /python_scripts /my_path/
<Directory /my_path/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

In this `/my_path/`, I have all my python scripts which I can access using apache2. but while accessing through browser, I just see plain texts (code).

I would like to beautify all python scripts.

Is there any way, we can achieve it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `beautify` means for you, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: instead of printing plain python script on browser, I want to apply some kind of css to them so it is colored properly.

Comment: I have tried to use .htaccess but didnt find success